# How to automate CA mainframe screen validations using selenium?

Tags: validation, selenium, automation, mainframe

We have an API where, if i enroll some data it will reflect in mainframe system, i need to validate few details using selenium testNG framework..Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Selenium isn't made for API Testing. You'll want something like SoapUI.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a Web Browser UI validation framework. If you are trying to validate api, then selenium is not going to be the right tool for you. You could look into SOAP UI or you could build your own custom api validation framework that hits an api endpoint, serializes it to an object and then validates the response values based on what you expect the response to be. I've also built hybrid frameworks where, I manipulate the browser via selenium and then at one point in the test I have to call an api to validate that another application was updated. But you wouldn't use anything from the selenium libraries for api validation.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is used to test GUI. If you want to implement API testing, you can use RestAssured framework if you like to code or SoapUI.